# How to add diagonal probabilistic hough lines

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, houghlinesp

In my code I'm detecting only vertical lines via HoughLinesP (OpenCV). Here's an example of an cut out output:

[image]

It was once a door, then I applied the canny algorithm. By setting only the 90 degree angle, there will be only vertical lines detected (the red ones). But now I would like to add also the green lines to this small section above a door.

The angle is calculated like this:

```
    double angle = atan2(ppt2.y - ppt1.y, ppt2.x - ppt1.x) * 180.0 / CV_PI;
    if (angle) {
        line(cdst, ppt1, ppt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, CV_AA);
    }
```

So how could I additionally detect the green ones? And especially only those above a door? 
Thanks!

Comment: It is a broad question, however, you could see what lines intersect with the vertical ones. Also it depends if your  `HoughLinesP()` has the correct parameters to detect those lines, that is a sufficient big rho, min count,etc. If you think this could work do tell me and I can elaborate a question

Comment: @GrayCygnus my `HoughLinesP()` looks like this `HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 2, 66, 50, 150);` actually if I increase the rho parameter, there would be more lines, wouldn't they? This would not be my aim. But maybe you could help me now by my given parameters?

Comment: In your code, what does `if (angle)` do? Appears to reject lines which are very very very precisely horizontal, why do that?

Comment: @barny as my first sentence says, I'm rejecting all horizontal lines to get only the vertical one.

Comment: "Rejecting precisely horizontal lines" isn't quite the same as "getting only vertical lines" - there are 88 degrees in between.

Comment: And also, atan2 can validly return +pi (which is why this form of the arc tangent trigonometic function is provided, it can be very useful) - this is a "horizontal" line that your test `if (angle)` doesn't reject.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276271/how-to-set-a-minimum-distance-between-probabilistic-hough-lines

Answer (score 0):

Your results are only showing vertical lines, and while yes you are rejecting precisely horizontal lines you might want to review what that test is actually removing. Also rejecting horizontal lines isn't the same as accepting only vertical lines, I think in this case you are basically only getting vertical lines from HoughLinesP.

Anyway, to get some more diagonal lines detected you will have to change the HoughLinesP theta parameter, from pi/2:

```
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 2, 66, 50, 150);
```

to, for example:

```
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180.0, 66, 50, 150);
```

And then you probably need to make your angle reject more robust/sophisticated to reject oddly angled lines as well as precisely 0.000000000000 radians lines as returned by atan2 and anyway it would seem to be a lot more resilient to e.g. small changes in picture angle, to check for a range of angles e.g. +/-0.01

Comment: unfortunally if I used your example, I get everywhere diagonal lines, not only at those specific parts..

Comment: You said you wanted diagonal lines, you've got loads, so I answered your question - so I hope you can upvote and accept my answer. Now, as I said in my answer, you may have to tune the HoughLinesP parameters and maybe your angle filters to select what you need. I don't know what you need, if you want help with that, it's probably a different question.

Comment: Is this some sort of assignment? Be honest.

Comment: Nope it isn't. But I already figured it out on my own. Anyway thanks. :)

Comment: Unfortunally not really, I created another solution. But anyway thank you for your effort!

Comment: Interesting. So you haven't changed the HoughLinesP theta parameter from pi/2?